# Table with jQuery hover fade effect

Tags: jquery, html-table, hover, jquery-animate, fade

Trying to get this code below to work in order to highlight the full row and not just one cell.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poxpsdza/2/)

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td[id*="dataRow"]').stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");

    $('td[id*="dataRow"]').hover(
    function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Any assistance would be great!

Comment: you can also do it with css only. something like http://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/EyABe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target `.parent()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td[id*="dataRow"]').parent().stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");

    $('td[id*="dataRow"]').hover(
    function() {
       $(this).parent().stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
       $(this).parent().stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/poxpsdza/4/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Emmanuel. Any possible way to also stop the animation from going crazy if you hover over all the tables real fast?

Answer (score 2):

Use [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('td[id*="dataRow"]').stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");
        
    $('td[id*="dataRow"]').hover(
    function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
        $(this).siblings().stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");
         $(this).siblings().stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");
        
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-checkable datatable dataTable" id="DataTables_Table_0" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_0_info">
 <thead>
  <tr role="row">
         <th id="dataTitle0" class="sorting_disabled" role="columnheader" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Event Date" style="width: 114px;">Event Date</th>
            <th id="dataTitle1" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Time: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 99px;">Time</th>
            <th id="dataTitle2" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Name: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 300px;">Name</th>
            <th id="dataTitle3" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Address: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 185px;">Address</th>
            <th id="dataTitle4" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Zip: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 37px;">Zip</th>
            <th id="dataTitle5" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Latitude/Long: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 148px;">Latitude/Long</th>
            <th id="dataTitle6" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="City: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 86px;">City</th>
            <th id="dataTitle7" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="State: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 33px;">State</th>
            <th id="dataTitle8" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="County: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 78px;">County</th>
            <th id="dataTitle9" class="sorting" role="columnheader" tabindex="0" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Advocate: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 60px;">Advocate</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
     <tr class="even">
      <td id="dataRow0" data-text="Event Date" class=" ">11/15/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
            <td id="dataRow1" data-text="Time" class=" ">12:00 p.m.</td>
            <td id="dataRow2" data-text="Name" class=" ">A place here</td>
            <td id="dataRow3" data-text="Address" class=" ">9999 west street name</td>
            <td id="dataRow4" data-text="Zip" class=" ">00000</td>
            <td id="dataRow5" data-text="Latitude/Long" class=" ">3.0442263,-21.1500054</td>
            <td id="dataRow6" data-text="City" class=" ">City</td>
            <td id="dataRow7" data-text="State" class=" ">ST</td>
            <td id="dataRow8" data-text="County" class=" ">County</td>
            <td id="dataRow9" data-text="Advocate" class=" ">Yo momma</td>
      </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
      <td id="dataRow0" data-text="Event Date" class=" ">11/15/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
            <td id="dataRow1" data-text="Time" class=" ">12:00 p.m.</td>
            <td id="dataRow2" data-text="Name" class=" ">A place here</td>
            <td id="dataRow3" data-text="Address" class=" ">9999 west street name</td>
            <td id="dataRow4" data-text="Zip" class=" ">00000</td>
            <td id="dataRow5" data-text="Latitude/Long" class=" ">3.0442263,-21.1500054</td>
            <td id="dataRow6" data-text="City" class=" ">City</td>
            <td id="dataRow7" data-text="State" class=" ">ST</td>
            <td id="dataRow8" data-text="County" class=" ">County</td>
            <td id="dataRow9" data-text="Advocate" class=" ">Yo momma</td>
      </tr>
        <tr class="even">
      <td id="dataRow0" data-text="Event Date" class=" ">11/15/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
            <td id="dataRow1" data-text="Time" class=" ">12:00 p.m.</td>
            <td id="dataRow2" data-text="Name" class=" ">A place here</td>
            <td id="dataRow3" data-text="Address" class=" ">9999 west street name</td>
            <td id="dataRow4" data-text="Zip" class=" ">00000</td>
            <td id="dataRow5" data-text="Latitude/Long" class=" ">3.0442263,-21.1500054</td>
            <td id="dataRow6" data-text="City" class=" ">City</td>
            <td id="dataRow7" data-text="State" class=" ">ST</td>
            <td id="dataRow8" data-text="County" class=" ">County</td>
            <td id="dataRow9" data-text="Advocate" class=" ">Yo momma</td>
      </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
      <td id="dataRow0" data-text="Event Date" class=" ">11/15/2014 12:00:00 AM</td>
            <td id="dataRow1" data-text="Time" class=" ">12:00 p.m.</td>
            <td id="dataRow2" data-text="Name" class=" ">A place here</td>
            <td id="dataRow3" data-text="Address" class=" ">9999 west street name</td>
            <td id="dataRow4" data-text="Zip" class=" ">00000</td>
            <td id="dataRow5" data-text="Latitude/Long" class=" ">3.0442263,-21.1500054</td>
            <td id="dataRow6" data-text="City" class=" ">City</td>
            <td id="dataRow7" data-text="State" class=" ">ST</td>
            <td id="dataRow8" data-text="County" class=" ">County</td>
            <td id="dataRow9" data-text="Advocate" class=" ">Yo momma</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use selector `tbody tr`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr').stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");

    $('#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr').hover(
    function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: I would but there may be other tables on the same page that I would not need them to have that kind of effect.

Comment: then you need to have selector like `#DataTables_Table_0 tbody tr`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simplify it and just target the row directly?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('tr').stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");

    $('tr').hover(
    function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
    },
    function() {
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0.2"}, "slow");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smurphy/5912eh8d/